In what senario the receiver is same as the signer in a transfer?

In this transfer, why the receiver of the transfer is also the signer? Shouldn't the sender be the signer?

The receiver's signature is required for claimed_locked because it ensures ownership and authorization. In cases like staking or vesting, funds are locked, and only the rightful owner (receiver) can unlock or claim them. The program uses the receiver’s signature to:

Verify they are the rightful owner.
Confirm their intent to claim the funds.
This prevents unauthorized claims and ensures secure program logic.


Thank u so much!

Given the instruction name Claim_locked, seems like the signer claimed some tokens that were in some other account.
So I would guess it's like a withdrawal: the signer is the one signing the transaction, and also the recipient of the transfer.

The receiver might also be the signer in a Solana transfer if the transaction involves initializing an associated token account, interacting with a program that requires the receiver's authorization, or custom logic enforced by the program handling the transfer.
